# Geolocation in Phonegap using GPS

Tags: cordova, gps, geolocation

I am working with geolocation in phonegap application. I get the location easily when High Accuracy and Battery saving mode is ON. But it gives error while working in GPS. Please help. I am stuck in it.

I applied the timeout upto 60000 milliseconds. But it didnot work even then.

The code is -

```
function Geolocation(){}

Geolocation.options = {
    maximumAge: 60000, 
    timeout: 15000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

Geolocation.errorMessage = 'Unable to get location data. Ensure that the location services are enabled in high accuracy mode. If enabled, try turning off/on location services and open this page again';

Geolocation.update = function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Geolocation.updateSuccess, Geolocation.highAccuracyError, Geolocation.options);
}

Geolocation.highAccuracyError = function(err) {
    if (err.code == 3) {
        var options = Geolocation.options;
        options.enableHighAccuracy = false;
        options.timeout = 15000;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Geolocation.updateSuccess, Geolocation.lowAccuracyError, options);
    }
}

Geolocation.lowAccuracyError = function(err) {
    Geolocation.currentLocation = null;
}

Geolocation.updateSuccess = function(position) {
    Geolocation.currentLocation = {};
    Geolocation.currentLocation.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    Geolocation.currentLocation.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: There is simply lowAccuracy error when i turn on GPS instead of high accuracy or Battery saving mode. In simple words, I am not able to get location even after 1 minute in case only GPS is ON

Comment: It is entirely possible that your phone is simply not able to get it's location based on GPS hardware alone.  For example, if you are underground your phone will not be able to connect to the GPS satellites.  And you don't need to be underground for that to be the case.  From what you have said I think Cordova is correctly reporting to you that the phone cannot determine it's location.

Answer (score 1):

@megha,
with the GPS there are two issues.

1) On Android, you *must* turn on all the location services, including GPS satellites, Google's location service, and Quick GPS. Otherwise, you will get that timeout error.

I think google broke it on purpose. It did not used to be that way.

2) When using GPS, you *must* be in motion - walking around for at least 20 feet (even if it is in a circle), And you *must* have line-of-site of at least 3 satellites. Most people get around this last problem by being in an open area -- like a soccer field or parking lot.

Jesse

Comment: Sir, I highly appreciate your answer. And surely , these are the issues.  But, I want to know what is the real solution to this problem because I have to capture all these issues programmatically as I cannot capture user's activities.

Comment: You cannot fix programmatically what you cannot control. You do not have control of the hardware, other than what you get from Phonegap or physics. GPS demands a certain number of satellites. There is no way around that problem. Most Apps ask that GPS be turn on all the time, but that drains the battery.     In any case, any answer beyond that is not on this forum.  --Jesse

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `watchPosition()` instead of `getCurrentPosition()`.

`getCurrentPosition()` makes a single request for the device position at that current point in time, so the position timeout may occur before the GPS hardware on the device has had a chance to get a position fix.

I'd suggest using `watchPosition()` instead to setup a watcher which will call the success function each time the OS receives a location update from the GPS hardware.

So, based on your current code, something like:

```
function Geolocation(){}

Geolocation.watchID;
Geolocation.minAccuracyInMetres = 50;

Geolocation.options = {
    maximumAge: 60000, 
    timeout: 15000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

Geolocation.errorMessage = 'Unable to get location data. Ensure that the location services are enabled in high accuracy mode. If enabled, try turning off/on location services and open this page again';

Geolocation.update = function() {
        Geolocation.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(Geolocation.updateSuccess, Geolocation.highAccuracyError, Geolocation.options);
}

Geolocation.highAccuracyError = function(err) {
    if (err.code == 3) {
        var options = Geolocation.options;
        options.enableHighAccuracy = false;
        options.timeout = 15000;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Geolocation.updateSuccess, Geolocation.lowAccuracyError, options);
    }
}

Geolocation.lowAccuracyError = function(err) {
    Geolocation.currentLocation = null;
}

Geolocation.updateSuccess = function(position) {
    // Reject if accuracy is not sufficient
    if(position.coords.accuracy > Geolocation.minAccuracyInMetres){
      return;        
    }

    // If only single position is required, clear watcher
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(Geolocation.watchID);

    Geolocation.currentLocation = {};
    Geolocation.currentLocation.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    Geolocation.currentLocation.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that your phone is simply not able to get it's location based on GPS hardware alone. For example, if you are underground your phone will not be able to connect to the GPS satellites. And you don't need to be underground for that to be the case. From what you have said I think Cordova is correctly reporting to you that the phone cannot determine it's location.