# cordovaGeolocation error: position retrieval timed out

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework

Hello I want to implement some geolocation features in my app.

So I implemented a watchposition function like this:

```
.controller('NavigationCtrl', function ($scope,$cordovaGeolocation) {

var watchOptions = {
  frequency : 1000,
  timeout : 20*1000,
  enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
};

var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
watch.then(
  null,
  function(err) {
    alert("WatchPosition failed: "+JSON.stringify(err));
  },
  function(position) {
    $scope.position = position;
  }
);

})
```

Well in the first call of the template I get a geolocation but than after 20 seconds I get an error:

```
code:3, message:'Position retrieval timed out'
```

I'm testing the app on a iPhone 5s iOS 8.3.

I googled around and found out that cordova 3.1 has some errors with geolocations so I choose to use the html api for geolocations like here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

but it didn't show me anything in my ionic-framework app.

What am I missing?

I'm using cordova 4.3.0 and ionic 1.3.19.

Comment: please see my answer here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301464/geolocation-in-phonegap-using-gps][1]

Jesse


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301464/geolocation-in-phonegap-using-gps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I have to put the code in a `$ionicPlatform.ready` function to be sure that the device is ready before it start geolocating. Now it working fine.